# Restoring Apple Mobile File Integrity back to default settings (nvram boot-args)

Tags: macos, terminal, sip, gatekeeper

I modified Apple Mobile File Integrity by running the following commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=1"
```

How do I revert this change and restore the macOS defaults settings for AMFI / nvram boot-args?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/MacEnhance/MacForge/issues/30#issuecomment-604647302, this can be reset by running

```
sudo nvram boot-args=""
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.libraryvalidation.plist DisableLibraryValidation -bool true
```

PS: I'm not sure about the second command though, maybe try the first and reboot to check whether it already solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was told I could do the following:

You can simply reset your nvram using the following terminal command:

`sudo nvram -c`